# open browser from VBA passing URL from a cell

Tags: vba, api

I need to open a browser from a VBA where the URL must be read from a cell. If I use the URL as string in the call, it's working fine but when I try to call the URL from a cell I got an error because it adds HTTP in front

this one works

```
Set browser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

browser.Visible = True

browser.Navigate ("https://ITMIXI01AP.ICSITA.NET/InforIntSTS/connect/authorize?client_id=infor~62hEkBLpdrXINBI5Byh4NVAu9JuZmpO7NyMANis65xU&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/redirect.html")
```

This one doesn't:

```
 wClientId = ws.Range("C19")
 wClientSecret = ws.Range("C20")
 wTokenUrl = ws.Range("C21")
 wTokenResource = ws.Range("C22")
 wRedirecURI = ws.Range("C23")


InforOSURL = Chr(34) + Trim(wTokenUrl) + Trim(wTokenResource) + "?client_id=" + Trim(wClientId) + "&response_type=code&redirect_uri=" + 
Trim(wRedirecURI) + Chr(34)
InforOSURL = Trim(InforOSURL)

Set browser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

browser.Visible = True

browser.Navigate InforOSURL
```

Comment: You don't need the Chr(34) at the start and the end.

Comment: if i remove the chr(34) it asks for saving the file, i need to open the url in a browser

Comment: If you put a breakpoint before `browser.Navigate InforOSURL`, what is the value of the `InforOSURL` variable?

Comment: if you keep the chr(34) IE will try to open a page named "http://%22https [...] .html%22", so you need to remove them, and there is propbably another error somewhere but sing we don't have your data we cannot guess.

Comment: https://ITMIXI01AP.ICSITA.NET/InforIntSTS/connect/authorize?client_id=infor~62hEkBLpdrXINBI5Byh4NVAu9JuZmpO7NyMANis65xU&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/redirect.html

Comment: try with any url you like, you get same issue

Comment: i did a mistake in the resource, i put connect/token instead of connect/authorize. it's working now. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the `ShellExecute()` function.

Besides of being able to open any document, it can also open and navigate to a webpage using the default browser. In addition by supplying the `verb` you can do actions like print, edit etc.

The example below has a static `Open` operation.

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                                                                               ByVal lpOperation As String, _
                                                                               ByVal lpFile As String, _
                                                                               ByVal lpParameters As String, _
                                                                               ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
                                                                               ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
Public Sub MyShellExecute(ByVal Path As String)
    ShellExecute 0, "Open", Path, "", "", vbNormalNoFocus
End Sub
```

To call it:

```
MyShellExecute "www.google.com"
```